# How to assess cancel safety of `select!`?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

I'm using Tokio runtime and I'm trying to build an interface which will return messages from several streams , but in this instance I cannot consume the streams with `StreamMap` or any `merge` method (streams will be owned by a wrapping object), so I plan to use `select!` statement for that:

```
struct Listener {
    alice: StructWithStreamField,
    bob: StructWithStreamField,
}
impl Listener {
    async fn listen(&mut self) -> Option<MessageAndSource> {
        select! {
            maybe_message = self.bob.stream.next() => {
                let message = maybe_message?;
                return Some(MessageAndSource::FromBob(message))
            }
            maybe_message = self.alice.stream.next() => {
                let message = maybe_message?;
                return Some(MessageAndSource::FromAlice(message))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Granted the `stream` field owned by `bob` and `alice` actually implements `Stream`, can I be sure that cancelling `listen` method is always safe, since there is no `await` point in between receiving message from stream and returning it? In more general sense, are there any guidelines for assessing cancel-safety? Or maybe there is a better suited solution?

Comment: Maybe I'm ignorant or something but what exactly do you mean by "canceling `listen`" in rust you (or your chosen runtime) has to poll `Futures` until they're finished. The concept of canceling a function doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: @cafce25 Cancellation *is* when you stop polling a future and drop it instead. This is something that is allowed to happen in Rust, `select!` does it, and "cancellation safety" is the matter of reasoning about whether cancelling a future will have any undesired effects due to it leaving some partially completed task.

Comment: Wait. Are you talking about the cancellation safety of the `select!` itself (that is, whether this `select!` is safe), or the cancellation safety of `listen()`, that is, whether it is safe to `select!` the future returned from `listen()`, assuming the `select!` it itself does is safe?

Comment: nit: your code contains typo: `Somme` should be `Some`

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I'm talking about the latter: what happens when whole `listen()` is cancelled. I can see now this is not clear, but I can't think of better phrasing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If the futures `select!` awaits are cancellation safe, so is `listen()`.

To verify a future is cancellation safe you need to inspect all points it `.await` at (including nested) and make sure that if we stop the future there no data will be lost. This is because futures can be only cancelled at `.await`s. Since there are no `.await`s, there's nothing to verify.

Of course, the user can still drop the result of `listen()`, but the same applies to any function, async or not.

Comment: Regarding the last point, so there is still a possibility that result is read from a `stream` in `select!`, and is never read by `listener()` caller, but the value was already taken from the inner `stream` right? Is there alternative approach that would only consume value from inner `stream` only when `listen()` result is consumed?

Comment: @Scherzo I don't think. But I don't understand why this is a problem: every function can have its result thrown away. If the caller wants to use it, the caller will use it.